When importing an STL file into Blender, it automatically fills in the blank spaces
I'm having problems with modeling. I'm trying to create 3D models of a hand.
I obtained the scans in XYZ format and then used CloudCompare to try to join the different segments. I was relatively successful, but there were holes that needed filling.
So, I created a mesh and exported it in STL to Blender. However, when I open the file in Blender, it automatically fills in the empty spaces, which I don't want. I wanted to know if anyone has had a similar problem and how they solved it.

Download .blend
